# First order system in polar coordinates : finding the trap region and showing it has a limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the following first order EDOs system,

$$
\begin{cases}
  \dot{x} = y + ax(1-b-x^2-y^2) \\
  \dot{y} = -x + ay(1-x^2-y^2)
\end{cases}
$$

where $a \in ]0,1]$ and $b \in [0,1[$

Switching to polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, I find the following system,

$$
\begin{cases}
  \dot{r} = ar^2(1-r) - abr\cos^2(\theta) \\
  \dot{\theta} = a\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)b - 1
\end{cases}
$$

I would like to show that this system has a **limit cycle**. How could I do that ? I was thinking about showing that some surface $S$ in the plane is a **trapping region**. Therefore I could show using *Pointcaré-Bendixson theorem* that inside there would be a periodic orbit (limit cycle).

However, I'm wondering how I could find this trapping region ?

I can see that
$$
0 < \cos^2(\theta) < 1
$$

And that
$$
ar^2(1-r) > 0 \quad , r \in ]0,1[ 
$$

$$
ar^2(1-r) < 0 \quad, r \in]1, +\infty[
$$

But then there is this $abr\cos^2(\theta)$ that is so annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polar form of the equations are
\begin{align}\dot{r}&=ar(1-r^2)-ab\,r\cos^2\theta\\
\dot{\theta}&=ab\sin\theta\cos\theta-1
\end{align}

Let $D$ be the annulus defined by $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-b}<r<2$. Then

- it does not contain any equilibrium points, in fact $\dot{\theta}<0$,
- on the outer boundary, $\dot{r}<0$,
- on the inner boundary, $\dot{r}=ar(1-r^2)-abr\cos^2\theta\ge\frac{3}{4}(1-b)ar>0$

Thus $D$ is a bounded trapping region without equilibrium points, so must contain a non-trivial closed orbit by the Poincare-Bendixson theorem.

Comment: How do you find that the annulus $D$ is defined by $\sqrt{1-b} < r < 2$ ?

Comment: @Mathieu By looking at the $\dot{r}$ equation and figuring out when it is surely positive/negative.

Comment: @Mathieu I modified the answer slightly to take account that $b$ could be $0$.

Comment: @Mathieu : you get that $ar(1-r^2-b)\le \dot r\le ar(1-r^2)$. Now find the intervals where the lower bound is positive, there $r$ is certainly increasing, and then where the upper bound is negative, there $r$ is certainly falling. In the right combination such radii then define a trapping region.